# ssrs sum group totals for specific groups and subtract for specific groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report like this:

[image: Expenses SSRS report]

I have grouped on group name called expense type. Ideally expense type has three types, 1, 2 and 3. I have used them to sum up in TOTAL in blue line.

Now I want to add the total of totals to brown tan line,

I want ( (total of group 1 + total of group 3 ) - total of group 2 ) in the tan color total billing submitted.

Can anyone help me in writing this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IIF()` or `SWITCH()` to check the Category of each value before you calculate the totals.

```
=(Sum(IIF(Fields!ExpenseCategory.Value = "Group 1", Fields!Amount.Value, nothing))
+ Sum(IIF(Fields!ExpenseCategory.Value = "Group 3", Fields!Amount.Value, nothing)) )
/ Sum(IIF(Fields!ExpenseCategory.Value = "Group 2", Fields!Amount.Value, nothing))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use report items to achieve what you want

for example..

```
=(Reportitems!group1total.value +Reportitems!group3total.value )-Reportitems!group2total.value
```

The above assumes that the property name for the group boxes are group1total, group2total and group3total

Comment: this did not work as i have grouped the tablix on expense type. which has 1,2, 3 values in db. i get the data in groups as 1 , 2, 3 and finally i have to write an expression where sum = (1+3)-2